# C Programing pthread print segmentation fault

Tags: c, multithreading, printing, pthreads, fault

Below is my code. I'm trying to get the `main_thread` to get user input, store in `global_variable`, then print out. However, after getting the input, my print out is Segmentation Fault. Anyone got any ideas?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

char* global_variable;

void *first_thread(void *ptr) {
    printf("%s \n", (char *)ptr);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *second_thread(void *ptr) {
    printf("%s \n", (char *)ptr);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *third_thread(void *ptr) {
    printf("%s \n", (char *)ptr);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *main_thread() {

    printf("Thread 1: Please enter a line of text [Enter \"Exit\" to quit]\n");
    fgets(global_variable, 999, stdin);
    printf("%s", global_variable);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main () {

    pthread_t t_m, t1, t2, t3;

    //const char *m1 = "Thread 1", *m2 = "Thread 1", *m3 = "Thread 3";

    int cr1, cr2;

    //creating threads
    cr1 = pthread_create(&t_m, NULL, main_thread, NULL);
    //cr1 = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, first_thread, NULL);
    //cr1 = pthread_create(&t2, NULL, second_thread, NULL);
    //cr1 = pthread_create(&t3, NULL, third_thread, NULL);
    //threads created

    pthread_join(t_m, NULL);

    printf("Global Variable: %s", global_variable);

    exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just saw 2-3 question from you in all code you create first thread as main thread but commonly a main thread is the thread that run main..parent thread of all.

Comment: your commented code looks incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't allocating memory for `global_variable`, so `fgets` tries to write at a random position in memory, leading to the OS detect memory violation and stopping the process by sending SIGSEGV  that causes segmentation fault.

Change the your main to something like this:

```
 int main () {

  pthread_t t_m, t1, t2, t3;
  global_variable = malloc(sizeof(char)*999);
  //const char *m1 = "Thread 1", *m2 = "Thread 1", *m3 = "Thread 3";

 ...more code...

 printf("Global Variable: %s", global_variable);
 free(global_variable);
```

Read [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)

Comment: you are suggesting C++ question taged only C, btw correct formatting

Comment: Ah, missed that. I'll clean this up.

Comment: Please mention about releasing the memory. And also, since other threads rely on the allocated memory, you need to make sure it is released *after* threads die.

Comment: Edit your answer, formatting corrected and added link for malloc.

Comment: @NewFile I like your comment :)

Answer (score 4):

Note declaration:

```
char* global_variable;
```

is not an array but a pointer, and you are trying to read as:

```
fgets(global_variable, 999, stdin);
```

without allocating memory ==> Undefined behaviour, causes of segmentation fault at runtime.

To rectify it, either allocate memory for it as @dutt suggesting in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19375940/1673391), or  `global_variable`  should be an array as `char global_variable[1000];`